# Using lodash is it possible to sort an array of objects using several parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) I’d like to be able to sort an array of objects like below (but much larger) by several keys, some of which are nested in arrays: The precedence would be:

1. Income to a given year (ie provide (say) 2012 and income would be
   used for that year for all elements)
2. displayInGraph (being true)
3. pinnedRow (being true)

I’d also like to be able to reverse the above.

I've looked in the [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) but cannot see the solution to my question:

```js
[{
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: true,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20000
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 30000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 40000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 44000
    }]
  },
  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: false,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20000
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 32500
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 50000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45200
    }]
  },

  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: false,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20400
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 38000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 30000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45000
    }]
  },

  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: true,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 21030
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 39000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 44000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45400
    }]
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance for solutions

Comment: fyi, your snippet is not valid javascript, (there are no keys for your year/income arrays).

Comment: @CRice, thank you - edited...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lodash to sort by multiple properties within an object by having the iterated function return an array of the properties that you want to sort.   This example will sort by property `a`, then property `b`, then property `sortkey`.

```
var input = [
 { a: 4, b: 5, data: 9, sortkey: "blue" },
 { a: 3, b: 9, data: 27, sortkey: "red" },
 { a: 3, b: 9, data: 4, sortkey: "green" },
 { a: 3, b: 3, data: 19, sortkey: "purple" },
 { a: 4, b: 3, data: 6, sortkey: "white" },
 { a: 5, b: 0, data: 0, sortkey: "orange" }
];

var output = _.sortBy(input, function(o) {
  return [o.a, o.b, o.sortkey];
});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeular/qog6h9ez/3/ .

You could then reverse the sort behavior by updating the array.  For example, if you wanted `a` ascending, `b` descending, and `sortkey` ascending, you can do something like:

```
var output = _.sortBy(input, function(o) {
  return [o.a, -1 * o.b, o.sortkey];
});
```

(I prefer `-1 * o.b` over `-o.b` to elevate the visibility of the reversal).

It would be a fun exercise to see how it performs vs the somewhat cleaner:

```
var output = _.sortBy(input, ['a', 'b', 'sortkey']);
```

...if performance is relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash has a [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) method which accepts as it's second argument either a string (as a path to the sort property), or a function (which returns the sort property), or an array thereof. So you can sort on multiple parameters by using an array of sort functions:

```js
const myArray = [{
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: true,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20000
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 30000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 40000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 44000
    }]
  },
  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: false,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20000
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 32500
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 50000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45200
    }]
  },

  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: false,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 20400
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 38000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 30000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45000
    }]
  },

  {
    displayInGraph: true,
    pinnedRow: true,
    dateRange: [{
      year: 2010,
      income: 21030
    }, {
      year: 2011,
      income: 39000
    }, {
      year: 2012,
      income: 44000
    }, {
      year: 2013,
      income: 45400
    }]
  }
]

console.log(_.sortBy(myArray, [
    item => (item.dateRange.find(range => range.year === 2012) || {income: 0}).income,
    item => item.displayInGraph,
    item => item.pinnedRow,
]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Finally, you can reverse the result by using the javascript built in array `.reverse` method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy)? It can receive a list of functions used to perform each step of the sort.

For example you can:

```
const year = 2012;
const getIncome = (obj) => _.find(obj.dateRange, {income: year});
_.sortBy(users, [getIncome, 'displayInGraph', 'pinnedRow']);
```